# iOS Private Directory

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, filesystems

I'm wondering if this snippet of code returns a directory that is private to an application and protected by the application sandbox.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
return [paths firstObject];
```

To test this myself, I wrote two applications. Application `prateek.writer` runs the following piece of code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *applicationSupportDirectory = [paths firstObject];
NSLog(@"applicationSupportDirectory: '%@'", applicationSupportDirectory); // This is used by the second app.

NSString *filePath = [applicationSupportDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfile.txt"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:applicationSupportDirectory
                                              isDirectory:NULL]) {
  NSError *error = nil;
  if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:applicationSupportDirectory
                                       withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                                                        attributes:nil
                                                             error:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"error %@", error);
  }
}

[@"Hello World" writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

The second application, `prateek.reader`, runs the following piece of code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
// This string is copied from the logs of the writer application.
NSString *applicationSupportDirectory = @"/Users/prateek/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/218F1365-5AF2-4003-83AF-6337E0EA8207/data/Containers/Data/Application/B8918247-5509-458D-AB9E-0F1273EAD2FE/Library/Application Support";

NSString *filePath = [applicationSupportDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfile.txt"];

NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSLog(@"Read file with contents: %@", string);
```

My reader app was able to read the data from the writer app.
I ran this on an iPhone 8 Plus and iPad Air simulator and saw the same results. Could it maybe have something to do with this being simulator, or the fact that these are apps created/signed by the same developer (me in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Application Support folder is specific to each app and is within an app's private sandbox. No app can access this folder of another app, **when run on a real iOS device**.

The simulator has no such limitations. It's one of the many differences between running on a real device and a simulator.

Comment: I see - is there any official documentation that describes this difference?

Comment: I'm not aware of specific documentation outlining every difference but off the top of my head: 1. Sim can reach outside the sandbox, device can't. 2. Sim filesystem isn't case sensitive, device is. 3. Sim can't send email, take pictures, has no compass or gyro. 4. Sim can't install other apps. 5. Sim uses a different architecture (Intel vs ARM). 6. Sim runs on Mac so it has access to a lot more RAM and a much faster CPU.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Is there any documentation that points out that the Application Support directory is private on iOS devices? I found a few macOS references, but nothing for iOS.

Comment: Everything in an iOS app's sandbox is private. See [File System Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW12).